# What Azure services to use for Larger Datastorage

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Looking for best azure services for holding and manipulating data for an e-commerce application (online book store) with millions of books.

As of now the e-commerce application is running over asp.net and on-premises SQL server. As stock availability and prices are changed very frequently (in every hour) so we are manipulating/ updating millions of data in a specific time-line. Millions of records are updating with in 30 minutes using SSIS packages.

Now as we are intended to move our application over Azure, so can some help me to select the best data storage service on azure which meets our expectations.

Expectations:
1- Can store relational data
2- Data can update with in strict timeline - uses minimum time to complete full transaction
3- Highly scalable and highly available

As an experiment I am managing these data with Azure SQL Database (P1-tier) but not fully satisfied. Because for those task where On-premises Sql Server takes 30 minutes to complete, Azure Sql takes more than 7 hrs for the same process. I also tried with batches but still struggling.

Can someone suggest the solution please.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be happy to help.

Unfortunately there is so much that's different between an P1 in a remote data center with a 99.99 SLA, automatic HA and very specific CPU/IOPS/Memory resources - and your on-premise server where the app logic, SQL Server are all running in the same OS context.  Putting network latency to the side, I would guess that the HW resources in this server (CPU/IOPS/memory) are many times larger than what resources an P1 has.

Using what data you already have, upgrading to a P2 will approx. double the resources available in this test, P3 will quadruple and so on.

Happy to talk offline to help you build a more apples to apples comparison.  guyhay at microsoft.com